# javascript access to mssql fails due to self signed cert

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have the following js script that accesses an MSSQL server (running in a docker container at 192.168.2.5). It does a query and returns the result:

```html
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   
    var sql = require('mssql');

    // config for your database
    var config = {
        user: 'userid',
        password: 'password',
        server: 'ipaddr', 
        database: 'DBname' 
    };

    // connect to your database
    sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        if (err) console.log(err);

        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
           
        // query to the database and get the records
        request.query('select * from tablename', function (err, recordset) {
            
            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send records as a response
            res.send(recordset);
            
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
```

The code runs fine using jsbox on ios but fails on the Mac with the following error:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 192.168.2.5:1433 - self signed certificate
```

I have 2 questions. Why does it run from ios and how to fix it on MacOS?

Comment: The real solution is not to `trustServerCertificate` like that link, but to add a real certificate to the server

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought I had tried that but I must have had a typo. It works with trustServerCertificate:true. And yes, ideally I would add a certificate that could be trusted but since I’m only running this on the local net or via VPN it’s probably not essential.